# How to prevent tinymce from adding class to every new li in list

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-5

I'm using the lists plugin from tinymce.

I have made a function that will add a class to one of the li elements in the list.
If I add the class to the last element in the list, every new li element added by the editor when hitting enter will have the same class.

I've tried looking into content filtering, but there it looks like I can only prevent any li element having a class.

How can I make tinymce add new li elements without a class?

What happens now:

```
<ul>
   <li>asd</li>
   <li>asd</li> 
   <li class="optional">asd</li> (updated by right clicking and selecting optional)
   <li class="optional">asd</li> (new elements when hitting enter)
   <li class="optional">asd</li> 
   <li class="optional">asd</li> 
</ul>
```

What I want

```
<ul>
    <li>asd</li>
    <li>asd</li> 
    <li class="optional">asd</li> (updated by right clicking and selecting optional)
    <li>asd</li> (new elements when hitting enter)
    <li>asd</li> 
    <li>asd</li> 
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a configuration option that tells TinyMCE to not bring styles from one root block element (`<p>`, `<li>` etc) to another:  `keep_styles`.

The documentation is here:  https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#keep_styles

The setting either takes `true` (default) or `false`. As an example:

```
keep_styles: false
```

If you set this to false you won't get the current list item's classes/styles brought down to the next list item.

Here is a running example:  https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/dNhaab

Comment: Thank you so much! This is basically answering my question perfectly. Sadly I oversimplified my question. I have a backend parsing the HTML generated by TinyMCE. The class itself can often contain generated classes from styled components etc, so to always read the correct class we pass it in a data-class attribute. TinyMCE will still repeat the data-class attribute even with keep_styles set to false. 

So my li elements in reality looks more like this: <li class="sc-leCVjZ dAVtyA optional" data-class="optional">text</li>

Any idea how to do the same with other attributes?

Comment: You would have to do that yourself via code - TinyMCE has no configuration option to do this for you.

Comment: Possibly worth noting that TinyMCE does have a `NewBlock` event that you can listen to via `editor.on('NewBlock', (e) => {})`. This is fired when pressing enter and passes the new element in the event. So you may be able to use that to manually remove the data attributes.

Comment: Using TinyMCE as an uncontrolled component instead of a controlled one and adding the following code fixed my problems: 

`code`
editor.on("NewBlock", (event) => {
    editor.dom.removeAllAttribs(event.newBlock);
});
`code`

Thank you so much both of you!